# Youtube 4K very high CPU

Tags: lubuntu, cpu, youtube

My Desktop PC:

- Asus P5KC Intel Q6600 2.4GHz 4Gb RAM DDR3 Geforce GT1030
- Lubuntu 64bit
- Geforce GT1030 driver version:- 390.12

I am using the right drivers from Lubuntu but my CPU is at 80% to 100% on YT 4K video

On YouTube playing on 4K @60fps I get very high CPU load. I've tried h264ify but it's still lagging with very high CPU load. I tried different Internet browsers including Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and a patched version of Chromium, but the result is the same.

I don't have this problem with Windows 10 (64-bit). There CPU usage is 10% or 20% to 30% on YouTube 4K video and all web browsers work excellently, the only problem is memory (RAM).

So that's why I tried Lubuntu.

Any solution?

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers. If you did already please [edit] and update your question including the drivers version .

Comment: using NVIDIA binary driver - version 390.12 from nvidia-390 (open source)
NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [Geforce GT 1030]

Unknown: Unknown
Using Processor microcode firmware for intel CPU's from Intel-microcode (open source)